# How to use a transaction across multiple services in nestjs

Tags: transactions, nestjs, typeorm

How can I use transactions in nestjs within a service function that uses other services?

```
 async update(authContext: AuthContext, id: string, updatePortfolioDto: UpdatePortfolioDto, isSaved = false): Promise<Portfolio> {
   
    const queryRunner = this.dataSource.createQueryRunner();

  await queryRunner.connect();
  await queryRunner.startTransaction();
  try{
    await this.sleeveService.deleteForPortfolio(authContext, id);

    const updatedPortfolio = this.portfoliosRepository.update(id, portfolio);
    await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    return updatedPortfolio

  }catch(err){
    await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
  }finally{
    await queryRunner.release();
  }
  }
```

The update is a service menthod that uses another service sleeveService and portfoliosRepository

That is my current code. However this does not work, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I solved it (perhaps not in the best way). But first, there's an important note about your code.

According to TypeOrm [documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/transactionshttps://)

> "DO NOT USE GLOBAL ENTITY MANAGER. All operations MUST be executed
> using the provided transactional entity manager."

That is, you should not update entities using **portfoliosRepository** inside a transaction block, but use **queryRunner.manager**.

Now, if you want to interact with other services that work with your entities within this transaction, your task is to pass an **EntityManager** instance (**queryRunner.manager**). The other service method you call must take an **EntityManager** as an argument. It is also necessary to save/update/delete entities in this method using this manager.

Let me give you an example. My transaction looks like this:

```
        const queryRunner = this._dataSource.createQueryRunner()
        await queryRunner.connect()
        await queryRunner.startTransaction()
        try {
            this._logger.log(`Депозит баланса ${sum} на баланс задания ${task}`)

            const taskBalance: TaskBalanceEntity = await queryRunner.manager.findOne(TaskBalanceEntity, {
                where: {
                    taskId: task.id
                }
            })

            userBalance.value = userBalance.value - sum
            taskBalance.value = taskBalance.value + sum
            await queryRunner.manager.save(UserBalanceEntity, userBalance)
            await queryRunner.manager.save(TaskBalanceEntity, taskBalance)
            await this._taskBalanceDepositHistotyService.create(queryRunner.manager, taskBalance, sum)
            task.status = TaskStatus.ACTIVE
            await queryRunner.manager.save(TaskEntity, task)

            await queryRunner.commitTransaction()
            return
        } catch (error) {
            this._logger.error(error)
            await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction()
            throw new InternalServerErrorException("Ошибка при завершении транзакции")
        } finally {
            await queryRunner.release()
        }
```

In this example you can see that I am calling a method of another service **this._taskBalanceDepositHistotyService.create(queryRunner.manager, taskBalance, sum)**, which looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class TaskBalanceDepositHistoryService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(TaskBalanceDepositHistoryEntity)
        private readonly taskBalanceDepositHistoryRepository: Repository<TaskBalanceDepositHistoryEntity>
    ) {}

    async create(entityManager: EntityManager, taskBalance: TaskBalanceEntity, value: number): Promise<void> {
        const taskBalanceDepositHistory = this.taskBalanceDepositHistoryRepository.create()
        taskBalanceDepositHistory.value = value
        taskBalanceDepositHistory.taskBalanceId = taskBalance.id
        await entityManager.save(TaskBalanceDepositHistoryEntity, taskBalanceDepositHistory)
    }
}
```

I understand that this solution is not the best, I would be happy to look at other solutions.

Comment: How should I be able to use queryrunner.save ? The portfoliosRepository.update(id, portfolio) comes from the portfolio repository which is a different repository and has its own implementation?

Comment: @EmekaObasi 
Its base mechanism of TypeOrm. For you example: 

const updatedPortfolio = this.portfoliosRepository.update(id, portfolio);

The same expression, but using EntityManager:

const updatedPortfolio = queryRunner.manager.update(PortfolioEntity, id, portfolio)